# Get street names within circle from geoposition

Tags: routes, names

I want to trace a route, and I want to indicate to peoples the nearest street of route (to enter to route).

I thought if it draws a circle and gets the street names of that circle..., if none of the streets is on the route, the circle expands until getting a street name on the route, and that's the name to suggest to peoples.

Maybe there any other way to get it, but I only thought of this one.

Thanks!!.
Jose.